# changing bash hotkeys

Tags: bash, readline

I would like to change some hotkeys in bash to match the dos prompt, 
because I go back and forth between them.  I see that in order to change 
some of the hotkeys in bash, I need to change the .inputrc file.  There 
are however some really strange characters there that represent keys, but 
I don't know which key they represent, how can I find that out?

Like these things are pretty odd looking:

```
"\M-OD": backward-char
"\M-[5~": beginning-of-history
"\M-[5D": backward-word
```

I am also trying to set the home key to beginning-of-line, but I don't know
how to represent the home key

Ted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you need is explained in the `readline(3)` manpage.  In particular,

- `\C-` is the prefix for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
- `\M-` is the prefix for <kbd>Alt</kbd>
- `\e` is an escape character, sometimes also rendered as `^[`
- in general everything else is literal (excepting some more backslash escapes), so `\M-[5D` means <kbd>Alt-[</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> on most keyboards.

The easiest way I find of figuring out what special keys translate to is to type them while running `cat`.  For example, on my system, pressing the <kbd>Up</kbd> key I get `^[[A` which you can type in readline syntax as `\e[A`.  Do the same thing to find out the key codes for <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, and anything else you like.

**Edit**: See also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24132/what-is-the-general-format-of-keyname-for-key-bindings-in-inputrc-file/24133#24133) from unix.SE.